# How to resample non-equidistant timeseries data in java?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, java

I have a lot of movement data from a sensor of an android phone. The sensor-data is not equally spaced. The first column is the timestamp, the second to fourth are the values. I have many of these files of various length.

```
1476998233373060.00 -13.724.029 -0.32222483 0.6645355
1476998243378590.00 -18.152.794 -0.24412125 0.8499975
1476998253388590.00 -2.187.418  -0.30240154 12.714.252
1476998263396320.00 -22.723.544 -0.34668386 20.311.832
1476998273406320.00 -2.164.714  -0.37845135 24.795.723
1476998283410820.00 -21.867.716 -0.54110456 25.763.245
1476998293416360.00 -2.237.784  -0.6974954  22.364.025
1476998303426360.00 -24.321.814 -0.8333628  19.332.075
1476998313436360.00 -2.759.505  -0.7860836  18.638.668
1476998323446360.00 -26.884.165 -0.6191631  19.814.253
1476998333456360.00 -22.407.222 -0.49433255 21.869.373
1476998343410860.00 -14.944.388 -0.36760736 25.031.233
1476998353420860.00 -0.94890594 -0.42283204 28.025.484
1476998363430860.00 -0.8609359  -0.38489643 29.441.748
1476998373440860.00 -0.85431504 -0.35977864 29.717.588
1476998383450860.00 -10.072.823 -0.47319135 29.098.034
1476998393460860.00 -12.651.224 -0.51026744 30.539.284
1476998403470860.00 -19.531.182 -0.8022793  33.434.896
1476998413480860.00 -29.464.073 -11.810.504 32.431.068
1476998423471860.00 -36.945.052 -13.393.123 29.437.609
```

As you can see, the timestamps aren't equidistant, but I need them to be equidistant because I want to extract features from it via FFT.

I know I can interpolate it, using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523685/520897).

What do I have to do, to get equally spaced timestamps? Matlab or python aren't an option.

EDIT:
So if ever someone finds this in the future and needs the answer... I used [this method to interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523685/520897). The step-width I used to interpolate is the one difference in these timestamps, which came up the most.

Comment: I crosspost this question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959548/how-to-interpolate-resample-unequally-spaced-timeseries-data-in-java ,because I got no answers. If this isn't allowed, please tell me and I delete the other post. The problem with the interpolation is solved already.